# How to cast elements in an instance of List with streams in Java 8?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Given the code:

```
public Statement methodCallByName(MethodDeclaration method, String string) {
    List<ExpressionStatement> expressions = method.getBody().statements().stream()
                                                .filter(s -> s instanceof ExpressionStatement)
                                                .map(ExpressionStatement.class::cast)
                                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return null;
}
```

I have the following error in Eclipse Oxygen:

[image]

Notice that `statements()` returns a `List` according to [JDT docs](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FBlock.html).

What is wrong?

Comment: did you try `javac`?

Comment: That’s the standard [*raw types*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/2711488) problem. `statements()` returns the *raw type* `List`, hence, all the benefits of Generics are disabled beyond that point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is caused by `statements()` returning the *raw type* `List` (see also [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/2711488)).

Raw types may not only provoke unchecked operations, but also limit the applicability of type inference.

You may fix it with

```
public Statement methodCallByName(MethodDeclaration method, String string) {
    List<?> statements = method.getBody().statements();
    List<ExpressionStatement> expressions = statements.stream()
        .filter(s -> s instanceof ExpressionStatement)
        .map(ExpressionStatement.class::cast)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    // ...
    return null;
}
```

The conversion from the raw type `List` to a list of unknown element type `List<?>`, is the only type safe conversion we can do here. Since you are going to check and cast the elements anyway, that’s no restriction.

But note that you should try to be consistent. Use either

```
.filter(s -> s instanceof ExpressionStatement)
.map(s -> (ExpressionStatement)s)
```

or

```
.filter(ExpressionStatement.class::isInstance)
.map(ExpressionStatement.class::cast)
```